# Invalid SSL cert error when connecting to elasticsearch using DBeaver es driver

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, dbeaver

I have trouble using SSL keystore or truststore to connect to Elasticsearch client using DBeaver. This is an elastic stack on k8s installation on my local machine. I followed this [official tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-client-apps-dbeaver.html) to set up a connection using DBeaver, but I have trouble figuring out how to make cert validation work.

I logged into the elasticsearch pod, downloaded the cert and key at `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs/tls.crt` and `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs/tls.key`. I combined them into a p12 format using this command:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in combined.pem -out cert.p12`

elasticsearch.config:

```
http:
  ssl:
    certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs/tls.crt
    certificate_authorities: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs/ca.crt
    enabled: true
    key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/http-certs/tls.key
transport:
  ssl:
    certificate: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/node-transport-cert/transport.tls.crt
    certificate_authorities:
    - /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/transport-certs/ca.crt
    - /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/transport-remote-certs/ca.crt
    enabled: "true"
    key: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/node-transport-cert/transport.tls.key
    verification_mode: certificate
```

However, I'm getting this invalid cert error:

[image]

These are the driver parameters:

[image]

What certs do I need in order to pass the cert check? I wish there was an insecure flag to ignore the validation since it runs in localhost.